# Does lxml parse HTML contextually?

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing, lxml

I'm using `lxml` to parse HTML:

```
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring
```

It parses trailing whitespace correctly in some cases:

```
>>> html = """<div>some <i>text</i> </div>"""
>>> html == tostring(fromstring(html))
True
```

But it seems to break when encountering unknown tags (such as the `blah` tag below).

```
>>> html = """<div>some <blah>text</blah> </div>"""
>>> html == tostring(fromstring(html))
False
```

How can I fix it to include trailing whitespace for all tags?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be due to the behavior of libxml2 (I've removed some error messages from the  version below):

```
>>> print libxml2.htmlParseDoc("""<div>some <blah>text</blah> </div>""", "UTF-8")
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div>some <blah>text</blah></div></body></html>


>>> print libxml2.htmlParseDoc("""<div>some <i>text</i> </div>""", "UTF-8")
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div>some <i>text</i> </div></body></html>
```

I am still probing for a workaround.  libxml2's XML parser doesn't exhibit this behavior, but I think it would work a lot worse on broken html.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set a flag in the parser itself to remove whitespace. I've done this when parsing xml like this:

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)

data = etree.parse(open(file),parser)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is the reverse of what the OP wanted: he wants to KEEP the whitespace. The problem is that the `HTMLParser` (which can parse ill-formed html) throws away the whitespace after `</blah>`, probably because of some html-specific cleanup.